# How to use the "oooo" parameter of the Format function in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, date, outlook, format

VBA Documentation for the [`Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755.aspx) function lists `"oooo"` as a possible parameter for date formatting supposedly ouputing:

> The same as mmmm, only it's the localized version of the string

I can't get this to display a month name, the actual output is "oooo"

Any idea on how to use this ? Do we have to specify a locale ?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2ececb48-d4bd-4469-8601-792dcf19e641/ooooing-and-aaaaing-with-format?forum=worddev